# Transformations between coordinate systems

Tags: graphics, coordinates

In a graphics engine, I have three three-dimensional orthogonal coordinate systems, `O`, `A` and `B`.

`A` and `B` are the result of two different transformations from `O`. I now want to calculate the transformation matrix R, which takes you from `A` to `B`. `R` should be the rotation and translation with respect to coordinate system `A`, not the original coordinate system `O`.

Which of the following is correct?

(1) B = A * R or (2) B = R * A

By doing some simple worked examples, it seems that (1) is correct. However, my intuition says that (2) is correct, because the transformation to `A` should be applied before the transformation to `B`, via `R`. Which is it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Depends if you left or right multiply to go from O to A or B. either way R will be `A^-1 * B` or `B * A^-1`

Comment: As @ratchetfreak says, this depends on the matrix conventions used in your application. The two forms are often called "pre-multiplication" (source coordinate system goes on the left of the transformation matrix) and "post-multiplication" (source on the right). OpenGL and math textbooks typically use post-multiplication, DirectX uses pre-multiplication, according to this reference: http://seanmiddleditch.com/matrices-handedness-pre-and-post-multiplication-row-vs-column-major-and-notations/ (though their differences in row & column major forms somewhat neutralize this)