# Pre- or post-multiplication for rotation between coordinate frames

Tags: opengl, rotation, matrix, coordinates

I have three 3D coordinate frames: O, A and B, as shown below.

[image]

I want to know the rotation matrix R<sub>AB</sub> between A and B, that is the rotation that is required, with respect to the frame A, to move from A to B.

Let us imagine that all I know, is the rotation matrix R<sub>AO</sub> between A and O, and the rotation matrix R<sub>OB</sub> between O and B.

So, what is the correct way to determine R<sub>AB</sub>? There are two suggestions that come to mind:

(1) R<sub>AB</sub> = R<sub>AO</sub> R<sub>OB</sub>

(2) R<sub>AB</sub> = R<sub>OB</sub> R<sub>AO</sub>

Now, my intuition is that (1) is correct, i.e. post-multiplication. This is because I am multiplying everything with respect to the local coordinate frame (as discussed in http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~whmin/courses/cse5542-2013-spring/6-Transformation_II.pdf).

However, when I compute this, I get a different answer to that which I get by inspection of the diagram. The correct answer, I have noticed, is equal to the pre-multiplication solution of (2).

Please can somebody explain to me why (2) seems to be correct, rather than (1)? I was under the impression that if all your transformations are with respect to the current local frame, then post-multiplication should be done, i.e. multiply the matrices from left to right as you move between each frame. However, when doing the maths, pre-multiplication gives the expected answer.

Comment: Are you sure your matrices are not transposed? OpenGL expects them in column-major memory layout. If they are stored in row-major, then that will cause them to become transposed and then you are expected to pre-multiply the transposed matrices to get the same results as post-multiplying the original matrices.

Comment: Yes, Andon points out that your question is possibly ambiguous. If you include either: a) the matrix math you are doing in mathematical notation, or b) the code you are using, the question will be more answerable. I like the picture you included, though! (dot means towards, cross means away?)

Comment: A/B = A/O * O/B = (O/A)^-1 * (O/B). Assuming you're using the same notation as me, (1) seems correct. Here, I use "/" to mean "with respect to". And "^-1" means "inverse." However, it seems what you want is "B expressed in terms of A", which would be the opposite expression, in which case (2) is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transformations between coordinate systems](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/95348/transformations-between-coordinate-systems)

Comment: Like @wondra voted, this question is the same topic as your previous two questions.  If you would like to refine the question, edit your existing one rather than posting a slightly altered new question.  Making duplicates only dilutes the help you receive.